# Saving multiple records with f.select in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model called `Professor` with the following:

```
class Professor < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum language: [:spanish, :english, :french]
end
```

I want to be able to have multiple languages assigned to each `Professor` so I have the following code in my form:

```
<%= f.select(:language, options_for_select(Professor.languages.keys.map {|language| [language.titleize, language]}), {}, { multiple: true }) %>
```

If I select all three options I get the following from the server

```
"language"=>["", "spanish", "english", "french"]
```

but in the console I get:

```
Professor Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "professors".* FROM "professors"   ORDER BY "professors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Professor id: 1, language: nil>
```

What is wrong here and is there a better way to approach it?

Comment: `enum` accept only one item in list.

Comment: OK, thanks. So how can I save multiple records into `language`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either [serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Saving+arrays%2C+hashes%2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns) your `language` column or (the preffered way) create many to many association:

```
# professor.rb
class Professor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professor_languages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :languages, through: :professor_languages
end

# form:
<%= f.select(:language_ids, options_for_select(Language.all.map {|language| [language.titleize, language.id]}), {}, { multiple: true }) %>
```

Drop `language` column from `Professor` and create `ProfessorLanguage`, `Language` models with necessary migrations.

Comment: So what columns do I have to put in the `ProfessorLanguage` model? Sorry I am new to rails...

Comment: `ProfessorLanguage` should have `professor_id` and `language_id`.